# Passing Array to HTML From JavaScript Getting One Value Only

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in my javascript function, it is an array
I want to put it somewhere in my HTML. I'm passing it by getting the ID of that input HTML. and assigning it a value which is my array. Here's my JS code:

```
function save(name, amount){
  var all_name = [];
  var all_amount = [];

  all_name.push(name);
  all_amount.push(amount);

  document.getElementById('javascript_data1').value = all_name;
  document.getElementById('javascript_data2').value = all_amount;
 }
```

However, I'm getting only one value passed. How do you suggest I implement this, in this case? Here's a bit of my HTML

```
<form action="{{ url_for('postmethod') }}"  method=post>            
                  <input type="hidden" id="javascript_data1" name="javascript_data1" />
                  <input type="hidden" id="javascript_data2" name="javascript_data2" />
                  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank you very much!

Comment: like `all_name[0]`

Comment: Why not assign the `name` and  `amount` amount directly on the value?

Comment: When you assign an array to something like `.innerHTML` that's always going to work with strings, the array will be converted to a string first. What is it that you *expect* that to do? What do you want to see on the screen as a result?

Comment: Also, the arrays involved (according to the code you posted) will always have only one element in them. So what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

If your array had multiple elements inside, you could do something like this to show them on the html:

```
document.getElementById('javascript_data1').value = all_name.join(',');
document.getElementById('javascript_data2').value = all_amount.join(',');
```